# What is the function of diode D3 in this circuit?

Tags: diodes

https://github.com/cubic-print/timeframe/blob/master/electronics/PCB_schematic_V3.JPG

[image]

This circuit to strobe some LED's and a magnetic coil. C1 is a 4700uF capacitor to "reduce flickering". What is the function of D3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What is the function of D3?*

It's a reverse polarity diode. In normal operation it does nothing but, if you incorrectly reverse the supply wires to J1, D3 will short out the wrong polarity supply and hopefully prevent the main circuit turning to smoke. If the 12 volt power supply is too powerful, D3 will also turn to smoke so realistically you should also use a 1 amp fuse.

Comment: also the 1N4007 maybe not the best choice for the job, a TVS diode with similar thermal dissipation would add some protection from transient surges.

Comment: @PeteW I'm unsure how you concluded that.

Comment: I am reasoning that it's in a position you might normally put a TVS, easy substitution. They both will shunt a reverse voltage, limited by package thermal as mentioned. TVS adds benefit of its designed purpose when the power is hooked up correctly. (the 4700uF will eat much of it but not fast spikes).

Comment: @PeteW Oh OK, I thought you meant the 1N4007s on the output of the MOSFETs.

Comment: Might apply to those as well, no?